# Weird cmake target_link_libraries behaviour

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use target_link_libraries to link to some external libs like this:

```
target_link_libraries( MyApp ${OTHERLIB_LIBRARIES} )
```

where the OTHERLIB_LIBRARIES is set as

```
set( OTHERLIB_LIBRARIES debug mathd networkd optimized math network )
```

Now interestingly Visual Studio linker line includes both debug and optimized libs: mathd networkd math network.

I know that this sort of usage works, but I can not find what could cause this to break.

Cmake 2.8.3 and Visual Studio 2005

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
set( OTHERLIB_LIBRARIES debug mathd debug networkd optimized math optimized network )
```